# About representations of $s$ and $-s$ of indefinite quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

Given any indefinite binary integral quadratic form $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ with discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ and $a,b,c$ not all zero.  Does there always exists a $s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $s$ is represented by $f$ but $-s$ is not. $s$ is allowed to depend on the quadratic form $f$. I am sorry for the bad title, however, I don't know how to title the question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2948780/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens with $$ x^2 - 5 y^2  $$

suggest writing a little program, let $x$ go from $0$ up to $50,$ then for each $x$ let $y$ increase from $0$ until stopping when $x^2 - 5 y^2 < -100.$ Along the way, record any values of $n = x^2 - 5 y^2$ with $-100 \leq n \leq 100.$ Then print out those numbers in order

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Some quadratic forms $f$ are multiplicative; that is, for any numbers $m$ and $n$ represented by $f$, $f$ represents $mn$, too.
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103829) shows how to prove that one particular quadratic form is multiplicative. It can be adapted for others. Now if $f$ is multiplicative and represents $-1$...

Comment: Thought it might help some future reader of this thread if it had the word "multiplicative" in it.